# Linear Algebra Quadratic Form Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

I asked this question the other day but I still didn't understand it.  Hopefully someone can get through to me this time.

I have a question that reads:

Diagonalize the quadratic form A(x,y) = 3x^2 - 12xy + 7y^2.

I am unsure what diagonalization is in this context.  I know what it means to diagonalize a matrix, say, A.  You find it's eigenvectors, put them into a matrix, say S, find that matrix's inverse, and work out S^-1AS.

If someone could explain, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagonalize a quadratic form means diagonalize the matrix of this quadratic form which is also the matrix of the polar form associated to it. In your example this matrix is

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}3&-6\\-6&7\end{pmatrix}$$ 
and notice that

$$A(x,y)=X^TMX$$
where $X=(x,y)^T$

**Added**$\quad$ There's a method due to Gauss and it consists to complete the square: so we get

$$A(x,y)=3(x-2y)^2-5y^2$$
so with the new variables $$x_1=(x-2y)\quad; \quad y_1= y$$
we get

$$A(x,y)=X_1^T\operatorname{diag}(3,-5)X_1=(PX)^T\operatorname{diag}(3,-5)PX$$

where is the transition matrix

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

**Remark**$\quad$ If we want use the first method i.e. diagonalize the matrix then we should do it *via* an orthonormal basis and this is possible since the matrix $M$ is symmetric real.

Comment: You, sir, are a genie.  I know I'm not supposed to write thank-yous here, but I'm going to do it anyway.  Thanks! :D

Comment: You're welcome:-)